# Video js remove controlbar permenantly

Tags: video.js

I am using video.js to play a splash screen video in an ionic app. Is it possible to remove the control bar completely from the player?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a [`controls`](http://docs.videojs.com/tutorial-options.html#controls) option responsible for this:

```
const player = videojs('my-player', {
  controls: false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.video-js .vjs-control-bar{
    display: none;
 }
```